# "Mocking where it's defined" in python mock?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-mock

I want to test an evolving SQLite database application, which is *in parallel* used "productively". In fact I am investigating a pile of large text files by importing them to the database and fiddling around with it. I am used to develop test-driven, and I do not want to drop that for this investigation. But running tests against the "production" database feels somewhat strange. So my objective is to run the tests against a test database (a real SQLite database, not a mock) containing a controlled, but considerable amount of real data showing all kinds of variability I have met during the investigation.

To support this approach, I have a central module `myconst.py` containing a function returning the name of the database that is used like so:

```
import myconst
conn = sqlite3.connect(myconst.get_db_path())
```

Now in the `unittest` `TestCase`s, I thought about mocking like so:

```
@patch("myconst.get_db_name", return_value="../test.sqlite")
def test_this_and_that(self, mo):
    ...
```

where the test calls functions that will, in nested functions, access the database using `myconst.get_db_path()`.

I have tried to do a little mocking [for myself](https://github.com/flaschbier/StillLearningPython/tree/master/mockplain) first, but it tends to be clumsy and error prone so I decided to dive into the python `mock` module as shown before.

Unfortunately, I found [warnings](https://www.toptal.com/python/an-introduction-to-mocking-in-python) [all](https://pythonhosted.org/testfixtures/mocking.html#gotchas) [over](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#id1), that I am supposed to *"mock where it's used and not where it's defined"* like so:

```
@patch("mymodule.myconst.get_db_name", return_value="../test.sqlite")
def test_this_and_that(self, mo):
    self.assertEqual(mymodule.func_to_be_tested(), 1)
```

But `mymodule` will likely not call database functions itself but delegate that to another module. This in turn would imply that my unit tests have to know the call tree where the database is actually access – something I *really* want to avoid because it would lead to unnecessary test refactoring when the code is refactored.

So I tried to create a minimal example to understand the behavior of `mock` and where it fails to allow me to mock "at the source". Because a multi module setup is clumsy here, I have provided the original code [also on github](https://github.com/flaschbier/StillLearningPython/tree/master/mockmock) for everybody's convenience. See this:

```py
myconst.py
----------
# global definition of the database name
def get_db_name():
    return "../production.sqlite"
# this will replace get_db_name()
TEST_VALUE = "../test.sqlite"
def fun():
    return TEST_VALUE

inner.py
--------
import myconst
def functio():
    return myconst.get_db_name()
print "inner:", functio()

test_inner.py
-------------
from mock import patch
import unittest
import myconst, inner
class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("inner.myconst.get_db_name", side_effect=myconst.fun)
    def test_inner(self, mo):
        """mocking where used"""
        self.assertEqual(inner.functio(), myconst.TEST_VALUE)
        self.assertTrue(mo.called)

outer.py
--------
import inner
def functio():
    return inner.functio()
print "outer:", functio()

test_outer.py
-------------
from mock import patch
import unittest
import myconst, outer
class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("myconst.get_db_name", side_effect=myconst.fun)
    def test_outer(self, mo):
        """mocking where it comes from"""
        self.assertEqual(outer.functio(), myconst.TEST_VALUE)
        self.assertTrue(mo.called)

unittests.py
------------
"""Deeply mocking a database name..."""
import unittest
print(__doc__)
suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover('.', pattern='test_*.py')
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

`test_inner.py` works like the sources linked above say, and so I was expecting it to pass. `test_outer.py` should fail when I understand the caveats right. But all the tests pass without complaint! So my mock is drawn all the time, even when the mocked function is called from down the callstack like in `test_outer.py`. From that example I would conclude that my approach is safe, but on the other hand the warnings are consistent across quite some sources and I do not want to recklessly risk my "production" database by using concepts that I do not [grok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok).

So my question is: Do I misunderstand the warnings or are these warnings just over-cautious?

Comment: I'm skeptical you're going to get much value out of mocking here. Mocking is useful when you need to test that an object *received a message* (usually some kind of modify state command). You're fetching configuration data in the middle of a function. This lends itself much better to a test on a complete feature, start to finish. For a tool that migrates data from one storage engine to another, the only things I would unit test are the actual data transformations you perform in code (i.e., not in SQL). And I would ensure that logic is purely input/output based, eliminating the need for mocks.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to do this. But the transformations produce "side content" for the database (e.g. newly found master data) and update it to the database immediately. This feels strange at first sight, but it makes code easy to understand, so I do not want to refactor this. During other refactoring and enhancements, however, I want to have regression. So I produced the idea of mocking only the configuration.

Comment: Something I have found as I've developed more is that it is very, very often useful to separate the "what" from the "when." This would imply that you can have functions/classes that do your transformation and return the data back, then other functions to perform the updates. If you don't want to change your code's organization, I would actually recommend going a full integration/functional/acceptance test route. Instead of mocking the configuration, switch to an actual configuration file. Use a configuration file that contains the test env parameters when you're testing.

Comment: Instead of the database name, I then would have to dynamically assign a configuration file name in the unit test, which leaves me with about the same problem. But after all, I am more interested in understanding why the caveats from so many sources seemingly do not apply in the comparatively simple case given above – maybe it was not wise to provide context because it is provoking discussion about that rather than about the question...

Answer (score 1):

Finally I sorted it out. Maybe this will help future visitors, so I will share my findings:

When changing the code [like so](https://github.com/flaschbier/StillLearningPython/commit/109cc0487379096a0d51e8476f3b15780b5188b7):

```
inner.py
--------
from myconst import get_db_name
def functio():
    return get_db_name()

test_inner.py
-------------
@patch("inner.get_db_name", side_effect=myconst.fun)
def test_inner(self, mo):
    self.assertEqual(inner.functio(), myconst.TEST_VALUE)
```

`test_inner` will succeed, but `test_outer` will break with

```
AssertionError: '../production.sqlite' != '../test.sqlite'
```

This is because `mock.patch` will not replace the referenced **object**, which is function `get_db_name` in module `myconst` in both cases. `mock` will instead replace the usages of the **name** `"myconst.get_db_name"` by the `Mock` object passed as the second parameter to the test.

```
test_outer.py
-------------
@patch("myconst.get_db_name", side_effect=myconst.fun)
def test_outer(self, mo):
    self.assertEqual(outer.functio(), myconst.TEST_VALUE)
```

Since I mock only `"myconst.getdb_name"` here and `inner.py` accesses `get_db_name` via `"inner.get_db_name"`, the test will fail.

By using the proper name, however, this can be fixed:

```
@patch("outer.inner.get_db_name", return_value=myconst.TEST_VALUE)
def test_outer(self, mo):
    self.assertEqual(outer.functio(), myconst.TEST_VALUE)
```

So the conclusion is that my approach will be safe **when** I make sure that all modules accessing the database include `myconst` and use `myconst.get_db_name`. Alternatively *all* modules could `from myconst import get_db_name` and use `get_db_name`. But I have to draw this decision globally.

Because I control all code accessing `get_db_name` I am safe. One can argue whether this is good style or not (assumingly the latter), but technically it's safe. Would I mock a library function instead, I could hardly control access to that function and so mocking "where it's defined" becomes risky. This is why the sources cited are warning.