# Flask app.config during unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

What is the best way handle unit tests that rely on calling code that in turn relies on the current app's configuration?

eg

code.py

```
from flask import current_app

def some_method():
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    value = (app.config['APP_STATIC_VAR'])*10
    return value
```

test_code.py

```
class TestCode(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_some_method(self):
        app = create_app('app.settings.TestConfig')
        value = some_method()
        self.assertEqual(10, value)
```

Running the test above I get an 'RuntimeError: working outside of application context' error when the app = create_app('app.settings.TestConfig') line is executed.

Calling app = create_app during the test doesn't do the trick. What is the best way to unit test in this case where I am needing the config to be read in the the application?

Comment: Actually you are not doing unit testing here, but integration testing. So either you will have to refactor code (e.g. pass the config) to allow unit testing or apply methods for integration test. That's the standard answer. [But I tend to stretch `unitest` also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068957/mocking-where-its-defined-in-python-mock) and I am eager to learn whether someone drops in with a cool idea. Maybe `mock.patch`ing `flask.current_app` or so...

Comment: The question I would ask is what exactly are you looking to test with the different config values? How should your app behave? Also, with the different app configs, can you utilize Flask's [test client](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/#the-testing-skeleton)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using accessing the app within an app context when you call some_method() to fix it replace your call with:

```
with app.app_context():
    value = some_method()
```